# Handing checkable menu item behaviour

Tags: android, menu

I created checkable menu item using:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<group android:checkableBehavior="single">
    <item android:id="@+id/music"
        android:title="Music" />
</group>
</menu>
```

and

```
 @Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {

        case R.id.music:
            if(item.isChecked()) item.setChecked(false);
            else item.setChecked(true);
            return true;
   }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Now how can i control the behavior of onClick.

I have media playing in different activities on different occasions.

How can I stop the media.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the ans, just control your actions and use .setChecked(true/false) and in menu.xml android:checkable="true"